# Wordpress terms order un back office

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I'm on Wordpress last version, I've created custom taxonomy and terms as usual but display in back office is not as usual ! Selected terms are all on the top of the list ! like on image : 
[image: selected terms]

There are lots of other terms in event but there are at the bottom of the list not in child of event. But in term list all is ok : 
[image: terms list]

So is there any parameter to do this ? I've search on plugins or in my theme but I don't see anything. It's a custom theme, I use it on other site without the problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The images you shared are broken so i cant understand your issue completely. However maybe using [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/) might solve your problem.